# Can't non-interactively change password on remote machine using sshpass and chpasswd?

Tags: ssh, sshpass, passwd

I'm trying to write a script that logs in a user over SSH and than changes that user's password. The line of code I currently use for that looks like the following:

`sshpass -p $password ssh $user@$ipadress "echo $user:$password_new | chpasswd"`

It always throws several errors at me. Is my approach even correct?

I've already tried without the last part of the line, which looks like this:

`sshpass -p $password ssh $user@$ipadress`

But that also gives me the following error:

> SSHPASS searching for password prompt using match "assword"
> SSHPASS read:
> SSHPASS read: $user@$ipadress's password:
> SSHPASS detected prompt. Sending password.
> SSHPASS read:
>
> Permission denied, please try again.
> SSHPASS read:
> SSHPASS read: $user@$ipadress's password:
> SSHPASS detected prompt, again. Wrong password. Terminating.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**: I just realized that chpasswd is not installed on the remote machine, that partly explains the errors. So why is sshpass giving me errors then?